# access to apache2 website using domain name and not server's IP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ip

as written in the title, I want to access to apache2 website using domain name only and not server's IP.

I would like to get a error 403 when trying to access the website with the server's IP.

How is it possible?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed, with help of this thread: https://serverfault.com/questions/511...uses-the-ip-ad

finally, I added this into /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf:

```
        <Directory /var/www/>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx\.xx\.xx\.xx
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

[...]
        </Directory>
```

Now, I have a 403 error when typing directly my IP adress, and I can access my website only by typing the domain name.

thanks all.